# Querying for related sets of objects in Django models

Tags: django, django-models

Assume that I've following classes in my model:

```
class User(BaseModel):
  ..

class Node(BaseModel):
  ..
  author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='%(class)ss')
  tags   = models.ManyToManyField('Tag', related_name='%(class)ss')
  ..

class Tag(BaseModel):
  ..
```

And now, I'd like to have a method in a `User` class, which would return all tags for the user's node:

```
class User(BaseModel):
  ..
  def get_tags(self):

    # Here some more querying for tags in selected nodes
    user_tags = self.nodes.filter(author=self) # What to add if possible?

    return ..
```

I'd like the `user_tag` collection to include all tags that were used in nodes that has been authored by a given user. How to achieve this without custom SQL?

Answer (score 0):

If have got your question correctly,this should do it,select_related() method recursively prepopulates the cache of all one-to-many relationships ahead of time.

More details [click here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#related-objects)

Comment: I think that `select_related()` is like eager loading related objects. What I'd like to do is just to perform some "select" to retrieve those related objects.. let's say like: `self.nodes.filter(author=self).tags` (you got the idea?)